# Autocomplete textbox with a list as datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have string list that has string data into it. 
I want to create a autocomplete textbox whose source will be this string. 
I am doing this in a user controls in c # asp.net. 
I am not able to do it so far. 
any idea.

```
 <asp:TextBox Width="300" runat="server" ID="txt_search_extantdata" />
```

and this is my list with data

```
 List<String> _searchsuggestdata = Returndata.Returnlistofdata();
```

I am using .net3.5 and VS Studio 2010.

**Is there a way we can do it without ajax tool kit and web service**

Comment: Have you looked at [jQuery AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)?

Comment: [TextBox.AutoCompleteMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @DJ that is for windows forms i don't see that property in my textbox.

Comment: yes that is for windows you could look at this [JQuery AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) example || [MSDN AutoComplete TextBox Asp Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autocompletetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) || [Ajax Tool Kit](http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/ajax-tutorials/using-autocomplete-in-the-ajax-toolkit/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take a look at this links(I dont have rep to comment same thing)

http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.com/2013/12/autocomplete-textbox-without-webservice.html

http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2014/06/autocomplete-textbox-in-aspnet-with.html